# how to set an Ending Point for Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an Alarm Manager that runs periodically , but I want to have a specific set of time that it will be running. For Example , lets say that we have a periodic Alarm Manager that is registered with a broadcast receiver and an Action is being performed every 30 minutes. The thing is that I want the Alarm Manager to be active for a specific time lets say 3 hours, so the Alarm manager should goes off  3 hours / 30 minutes or 6 times.

Code to start the define the Alarm Manager:

```
TimerPeriodic = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ALARM_ID, Constants.TIMER_PERIODIC_ID);
    TimerPeriodicPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Fire Alarm Manager:

```
long start = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(StartMinutes);
TimerPeriodic.setRepeating(
                            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + start, start, TimerPeriodicPendingIntent);
```

Also the alarm Manager should be active if the Application is killed.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: use sequential alarm manager and recalculate next alarm when handles current. than you can set any interval you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be acheived by using Sqlite Db. where you store the Alaram ID,count,and repeation (How many time you want to repeat).

when Alarm is trigger (AlarmReceiver.onReceive()) increment the count check with the condition with repeation. if it exceed just cancel it. Hope It will help :)

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    cancelAlarm(reminder.getId(),myIntent,alarmManager);
      }

    private void cancelAlarm(int notiId,Intent myIntent,AlarmManager alarmManager) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notiId, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
     }
```

Comment: And how I can cancel Alarm Manager via Alarm Receiver on Receive ? My Alarm Manager is set via my Fragment

Comment: Ok, I know how to cancel an Alarm Service the problem is that I assign the Alarm Manager through a Fragment , also my Alarm Service is not a inner class , and I don't have the instance of the Alarm Manager inside it

Comment: sorry if I doesn't get you. Alarm Manager is a system service. you can get the same instance across all the fragment,activity and broadcast receiver using your application context. and i need to check more code that clear me the exact problem.

Comment: Yes you have right , I did implement something like your approach and worked ! Thank you

Comment: Thank you so Much! Happy to help you :)